# Import Data From Barcode Scanner to Sqlite Database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, import, barcode-scanner

I have an Opticon OPN-2001-USB barcode scanner.
I also have an input field for the collection of information to insert into my sqlite database.

I want to have a GUI that contains a button. This button will then import specific information from the barcode scanner and place it in a sqlite database.

I do not have any idea where to begin with this aspect.

I have the database and respective `python` script that inserts information by user input, but I would prefer the barcode scanning method to avoid errors.

I have read many articles and cannot find any specific documentation regarding this.

Opticon has wedge software that imports all the information, but it goes to a .csv file and then to import that file as well will be time wasted and another area for possible errors.

The current script input is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
import sys
from datetime import datetime

dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

root = Tk()
root.geometry('380x250')
root.title("Balances")
root.config(bg="lightblue1")
style = Style()

OrderNo = StringVar()
Balance = StringVar()

with sqlite3.connect('Reflex Footwear.sql3') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    my_data = cursor.execute( "SELECT OrderNo FROM PlanSandal WHERE Factory=?", ("RF1",))
    my_list = [r for r, in my_data]
    options = StringVar()
    options.set(my_list[0])


def update_clicking():
    code = options.get()
    balance = Balance.get()

    with sqlite3.connect('Reflex Footwear.sql3') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE SandalProduction SET Clicking=Clicking-? WHERE Order2=?', [balance, code, ])
        cursor.execute('UPDATE SandalProduction SET Closing=Closing+? WHERE Order2=?', [balance, code, ])
        cursor.execute(r'INSERT INTO ProductionBreakdown (Factory,Date,Order2,Clicking) VALUES(?,?,?,?)', [
                       "RF1", timestampStr, code, balance])
        updated = cursor.rowcount
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit(updated)


# Inserting labels and field of input
label_0 = Label(root, text="Clicking Score", background="lightblue1",
                width=20, font=("Arial", 20, "bold")).place(x=80, y=23)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Order No.", width=20, background="lightblue1", font=(
    "Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=20, y=100)
option_1 = OptionMenu(root, options, *my_list).place(x=180, y=100)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Quantity Clicked", width=20,
                background="lightblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=20, y=140)
entry_2 = Entry(root, textvar=Balance, background="lightblue1",
                font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=180, y=140)


# Style of buttons
style.configure('C.TButton', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground='red')
style.configure('S.TButton', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground='blue')

# Inserting buttons
submit1 = Button(root, text='Submit', style='S.TButton',
                 width=11, command=update_clicking).place(x=20, y=190)
exit1 = Button(root, text='Close', style='C.TButton', width=11,
               command=root.destroy).place(x=260, y=190)

root.mainloop()
```

This is only as a guideline on current input, based on the variable and updating the value in the database.

Any and all help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually scanner act as replacing or complementing keyboard entry, so if you can make keyboard input the scanner can do the work with no change in software. You have to check that the scanner can send an equivalent of <enter> key at the end of a successfull barcode scan.

Comment: @kunif The batch mode would be much more beneficial. To my understanding the retrieving of information could be done by the wedge software. I could program it in such a way that upon reading a certain barcode, it would serve as a <enter> key. In short, the configuration of the scanner is done by the wedge software, but how and when it retrieves the information would be defined by the written script. Please see my altered question for an included extract from my current script. Thank you

Comment: The presented source code cannot reproduce the problem due to lack of import etc. Please add by referring to this help article. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) And since it seems that the csv file to be used is also required for investigation and confirmation, please add the sample data.

Comment: @kunif Please see updated code in question above. This is the script that runs upon click from my main GUI.

Comment: A valid SqLite3 database file is required for the script to work. When I start it, I get an error that there is no PlanSandal table on Line 21. Then add sample data and routing information to reproduce the problem. And please add the details of which part was solved and what kind of result was solved.

Comment: @kunif Please find Github repo [link](https://github.com/ReflexTech1/python_script/tree/main/PersonalTest) This link contains the database and script in question. Please let me know if you need any further information. Thank you

Comment: The repository for that link doesn't seem to be public. Then add that information to the question article with a description of the new situation, rather than writing it in the comments.